# Using base class pointer against derived class object on stack vs. heap

Tags: c++, class, pointers, radix

I have a question on assigning a derived class object with base class pointer...

```
class Base 
{ 
    void print() { cout<<"Class Base"; }

};

class Derived: public Base
{ 
    void print() {  cout<<"class Derived"; }

};

int main()
{
    Base b, *bp;
    Derived d, *dp;

    b.print();
    d.print();
    bp = d; // why is this a conversion error? getting an error "cannot convert ‘Derived’ to ‘Base*’ in assignment"

    bp = new B(); // this works fine...

}
```

Does it mean that we can only assign a dynamically allocated derived class object to a base class pointer?? why is that so???

Comment: Where is `ap` declared? This code won't even compile because `ap` is not declared.Show us the *actual* code.Also, You cannot assign objects to pointers,You can assign addresses to pointers.You should pick up a [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: my bad... it was suppose to be bp :(

Comment: +1 for a well-constructed first post

Answer (score 7):

`bp` is a pointer here, and you are trying to assign an object to it. Try assigning the address of that object instead: `bp = &d;`

Comment: @w00te, I cheated ... I added the C++ tag.

Answer (score 0):

Derived isn't a pointer, its an object.  You need to get the address of that object to assign it to a pointer (which holds an address!):

```
bp = &d;
```

Works fine.